# Creating a reducer through a get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to make a menu, whose items are defined by an object received through a get request (it is all done dynamically through the backend of the application).

The object will have the following format:

```
[
    {
        id: "Option1",
        subtopics:[
            {
                id: "Option 1-1",
                subtopics: [
                    {
                        title: "Option 1-1-1"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Option 1-1-2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "Option 1-2",
                subtopics: [
                    {
                        title: "Option 1-2-1"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Option 1-2-2"
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        id: "Option2",
        subtopics:[
            {
                id: "Option 2-1",
                subtopics: [
                    {
                        title: "Option 2-1-1"
                    },
                    {
                        title: "Option 2-1-2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: "Option 2-2",
                subtopics: [
                    {
                        title: "Option 2-2-1"
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

What I would like to do is to display a Menu with only Option 1 and Option 2 displayed. When I click on Option 1, all of it's subtopics will be displayed and when I click on it's subtopics, all of their subtopics will be displayed and so on. (this in the format of  a tree menu)

After thinking quite a bit about this, I feel the only way to do this is by using Redux. However I am really not sure where to go from here.

As it is now, I tried to setup a get request for this object in a reducer, but I am getting the following error:

`Error: Reducer "topic" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined.`

Here is the current code for my reducer:

```
export default function(){
    const request = axios.get(theUrl)
        .then(function(response){
            return response.data; //the entire object array
        })
}
```

Keep in mind that the URL being called is indeed valid, I have tested it in other parts of the app.

I guess to add to the question, am I even doing this the right way? If not, how can I dynamically generate this menu and make a 'menu tree' by clicking in each main topic if not with redux?

Thanks!

Comment: _"the only way to do this is by using Redux"_ is pretty much never the case. Redux helps when you have lots of complex actions to coordinate, but it's no better than `setState` for simple actions like this.

Comment: And I think you misunderstand reducers - a reducer is a _pure function_ (so no AJAX) that takes the current state of the app and an action, and returns the new state. You don't call it directly; you `dispatch` an action, and Redux calls the reducer for you.

Comment: @joews Oops! Then clearly I was wrong on how I am going on about this. But if it's not through reducers, how in the world could I make this menu tree just with the component?

Comment: @theJuls you can use component state to store the menu data instead of redux to keep it in component only.

Comment: Write a `Menu` component. Make your AJAX request in its `componentWillMount`. In the success handler, call `this.setSetState({ menuData: response })`. In the `render` method return a list of child `MenuItem` elements, passing each one submenu from your Menu's `this.state.menuData`.

Comment: This (what you both said) is actually roughly what I had been doing before thinking I would need a reducer to make this work.
However I have no idea what I can do to by default only show the two main Options, and only when clicking them, show the subcategories. Keep   in mind that the number of main options is also dynamic, so I'd have no idea how much of those I'd actually have.

Comment: You could add an `isExpanded` boolean to each of your menu items. In your `render` method, only render the expanded menu where `isExpanded === true`.

Answer (score 1):

api calls should be placed in actions, when  api  call gets complete then pass the result to reducer and in reducer use initial state a blank object,

In Component, during componentWillMount initiate the action if prop contains empty menu object